# Wrong Target Generate Package TDS Sitecore

Tags: c#, sitecore, tds

I have a TDS Project file. When I build, it will generate sitecore package item to build output path. However, it create package to the wrong folder directory.

In the project properties, I set my build output path to

> ......\Build\Deploy\

However, afer build the package is generate to

> ......\Build\Package Release\

It create automatically a folder package release outside the deploy folder.. or can be said ignoring the deploy folder

Any thought would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try to set the `Build Output Path :` like this`..\..\..\Build\Deploy\Package_Release`

Answer (score 3):

That's the correct/default behaviour. The `Build Output Path` is where the solution is output to before being packaged up and place in the `Package Release` or `Package Debug` folder.

> **Build Output Path** – Sets the location TDS will use to collect the files to be deployed or packaged.

http://hedgehogdevelopment.github.io/tds/chapter4.html#build

There isn't any setting to control this as far as I am aware.

Update your build/deploy scripts according to look for the package in `build\Package Release` folder.

Comment: is this means build is the default folder? So, if I set the build output path to  build -> deploy, It will not create the new folder package release inside deploy folder : build -> deploy -> package release but instead at build -> package release ignoring the deploy folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MSBuild command

MSBuild.exe 'Projectpath' /T:Package /P:Configuration=Sitecore.Package/p:SkipExtraFilesOnServer=True; DeployOnBuild=true;PackageLocation='destinationpathFile'

example :
MSBuild.exe D:\Projects\sitecore811\Source\Presentation\Company.Web.Presentation\Company.Web.Presentation.csproj /T:Package /P:Configuration=Sitecore.Package/p:SkipExtraFilesOnServer=True;DeployOnBuild=true;PackageLocation="D:\Package\"

Hope it can help you...:)

Comment: Your answer is really helpful in bad way.. Thanks